# Can not justify my data in vb

Tags: vb.net

```
  Dim cel As Integer = 0, fah As Integer = 32
    If Len(cel) = 3 Then
        Do While cel <= 100 And fah <= 212
            lblCel.Text = lblCel.Text & vbCrLf & cel
            cel = cel + 5
            lblFah.Text = CStr(HorizontalAlignment.Right)
            lblFah.Text = lblFah.Text & vbCrLf & fah
            fah = CInt(9 / 5 * cel + 32)
        Loop
    End If
```

This is the code I wrote. Unfortunately, it does not work as I thought.

I want to justify my data alignment from left to the right. But it didn't work.

Can some one please help me to correct this?

Comment: Which are you using, VB6 or VBA? Neither allows you to initialize a variable when you declare it, so your code shouldn't even compile.

Comment: its in visual basic, so maybe VBA. sorry,i'm really new in program field.

Comment: A useful first step would be to determine what language you are using :). Then tag your questions appropriately. In VBA you definitely need to have `cel = 0` on a separate, later line of code than `Dim cel as Integer`. You can't do both in one statement unless you are using VB.Net.

Answer (score 0):

You put `cel = 0`.  Then you check for `Len(cel) = 3`.  Off the top of my head, I'd guess it isn't.

Comment: Get rid of "If Len(cel) = 3 Then" and the matching "End If" or else none of your code will ever run.